# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java

```
SELECT SUBSTR(MESG,98,15) AS ACC,FROM TBAADM.RTT WHERE CUST_OR_CARD_ID= "+No+"'" +
                   "AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE_TIME,'MM-DD-YY'))= "+tranDate+"'" +
                   "AND TO_NUMBER(SNO)=' "+sno+"'" +
                   "AND DCC_ID='SWT' AND CMD='PRCR' AND BANK_ID='PMC01' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have extra quotations at some places or miss them some where else. And the extra comma should be deleted before `From`.

```
"SELECT SUBSTR(MESG,98,15) AS ACC FROM TBAADM.RTT WHERE CUST_OR_CARD_ID= '"+No+"' " +
                   "AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE_TIME,'MM-DD-YY'))= '"+tranDate+"' " +
                   "AND TO_NUMBER(SNO)= "+sno+" " +
                   "AND DCC_ID='SWT' AND CMD='PRCR' AND BANK_ID='PMC01' ";
```